# Python: For loop only loops over the first part of a txt file

Tags: python, file, loops

Recently I had to make a script for my internship to check if a subnet occurs in a bunch of router/switch configs.

I've made a script that generates the output. Now I need a second script (I couldn't get it to work into one), that reads the output, if the subnet occurs write it to `aanwezig.txt`, if not write to `nietAanwezig.txt`.

A lot of other answers helped me to make this script and it works but it only executes for the first 48 IPs and there are over 2000...

The code of `checkOutput.py`:

```
def main():

    file = open('../iprangesclean.txt', 'rb')
    aanwezig = open('../aanwezig.txt', 'w')
    nietAanwezig = open('../nietAanwezig.txt', 'w')
    output = open('output.txt', 'rb')

    for line in file:
        originalLine = line
        line.rstrip()
        line = line.replace(' ', '')
        line = line.replace('\n', '')
        line = line.replace('\r', '')
        one,two,three,four = line.split('.')

        # 3Byte IP:
        ipaddr = str(one) + "." + str(two) + "." + str(three)

        counter = 1
        found = 0   
        for lijn in output:

            if re.search("\b{0}\b".format(ipaddr),lijn) and found == 0:
                found = 1                               
            else:
                found = 2

            print counter
            counter= counter + 1

        if found == 1:
            aanwezig.write(originalLine)
            print "Written to aanwezig"
        elif found == 2:
            nietAanwezig.write(originalLine)
            print "Written to nietAanwezig"
        found = 0

    file.close()
    aanwezig.close()
    nietAanwezig.close()


main()
```

The format of iprangesclean.txt is like following:

```
10.35.6.0/24
10.132.42.0/24
10.143.26.0/24
10.143.30.0/24
10.143.31.0/24
10.143.32.0/24
10.35.7.0/24
10.143.35.0/24
10.143.44.0/24
10.143.96.0/24
10.142.224.0/24
10.142.185.0/24
10.142.32.0/24
10.142.208.0/24
10.142.70.0/24
and so on...
```

Part of `output.txt` (I can't give you everything because it has user information):

```
*name of device*.txt:logging 10.138.200.100
*name of device*.txt:access-list 37 permit 10.138.200.96 0.0.0.31
*name of device*.txt:access-list 38 permit 10.138.200.100
*name of device*.txt:snmp-server host 10.138.200.100 *someword*
*name of device*.txt:logging 10.138.200.100
```

Comment: That is not a Python program. Edit the question and correct the indentation.

Comment: We don't know `output.txt`

Comment: On a side note, you should consider cleaning up your code and getting rid of the redundant lines first. Perhaps something like: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/11394195

Comment: Could you also provide lines 46 to 50 of `output.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this change:

```
for lijn in output:
    found = 0 # put this here
    if re.search("\b{0}\b".format(ipaddr),lijn) and found == 0:
        found = 1
    else:
        found = 2

    print counter
    counter= counter + 1

    """Indent one level so it us in the for statement"""
    if found == 1:
        aanwezig.write(originalLine)
        print "Written to aanwezig"
    elif found == 2:
        nietAanwezig.write(originalLine)
        print "Written to nietAanwezig"
```

If I understand the problem correctly, this should guide you to the right direction. The `if statement` is currently not executed in the `for statement`. If this does solve your problem, then you don't need the `found` variable either. You can just have something like:

```
for counter, lijn in enumerate(output, 1):
    if re.search("\b{0}\b".format(ipaddr),lijn):
        aanwezig.write(originalLine)
        print "Written to aanwezig"
    else:
        nietAanwezig.write(originalLine)
        print "Written to nietAanwezig"

    print counter
```

Please let me know if I have misunderstood the question.

**Note** I haven't tested the code above, try them out as a starting point.

Comment: I implemented the if found == 1 .... into the for loop and it seems to work like it should but it has still the same problem: he only does the first 48 lines of the 2337... I've doublechecked, there are no spaces or whatsoever around line 48 in the iprangesclean.txt